# Laravel cURL POST Throwing TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, rest, curl, laravel-5

I have a problem with POST cURL request to my application.
Currently, I'm building RESTFUL registration function using laravel 5.

The routes for this is example is

`localhost:8000/user/create`

I pass value using cURL function on terminal

```
curl -d 'fname=randy&lname=tan&id_location=1&email=randy@randytan.me&password=randytan&remember_token=Y&created_at=2015-03-03' localhost:8000/auth/register/
```

And this is my routes.php

`Route::post('user/create', 'UserController@create');`

And this is my function to store the registration user

```
public function create()
    {
        //function to create user.
        $userAccounts = new User;
        $userAccounts->fname = Request::get('fname');
        $userAccounts->lname = Request::get('lname');
        $userAccounts->id_location = Request::get('id_location');
        $userAccounts->email = Request::get('email');
        $userAccounts->password = Hash::make(Request::get('password'));
        $userAccounts->created_at = Request::get('created_at');

        $userAccounts->save();

        return Response::json(array(
                'error' => false,
                'user'  => $userAccounts->fname . " " . $userAccounts->lname
            ), 200);

    }
```

Executing the cURL syntax above, I'm getting this error `TokenMismatchException`

**Do you have any ideas?**

Because I'm implementing middleware only in my few urls, and this cURL registration url is not tight into any authentication mechanism.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel 5 enforces CSFR token authentication in middleware by default.

1. you can disable CSFR on selected route Here is the [link](http://www.techigniter.in/tutorials/disable-csrf-check-on-specific-routes-in-laravel-5/)
2. or you can try some of these [solutions](http://laravel.io/forum/11-14-2014-disabling-the-csrf-middleware-in-laravel-5). Hope so it will help.
3. changing your csfr token method `/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

   `public function handle ($request, Closure $next)
            {
               if ( !$request->is("api/*"))
               {
                   return parent::handle($request, $next);
               }
                return $next($request);
            }`

Comment: Thank for the link in 2. I ended up modifying `handle(...)` function in class `VerifyCsrfToken`. I added `if( $request->is( "api*" ) ) return $next($request);` just before the return. Now all requests to /api* get through CSFR.

Comment: Is it a public API? Because you shouldn't disable Csrf unless you are happy for anyone to send the API requests

Answer (score 10):

In Laravel 5 (latest version) you can specify routes you want to exclude in  **/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'rest-api/*', # all routes to rest-api will be excluded.
    ];


}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i needed to add the route on **api.php** instead of **web.php**